# MASConstraintMaker install Crash occasionally online

Tags: ios, objective-c, masonry

Below is my crash stack:

```
Incident Identifier: F3839E3E-31AC-469-1C64FEE04228
Hardware Model: iPhone13,2
Process: MyApp [19473]
Path: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/F82F8173-6349-472C-BEE3-33F2CA413EB6/MyApp.app/MyApp
Identifier: com.myapp
Version: 11.00.05 (498469)
Code Type: ARM-64
Parent Process: [1]

Date/Time: 2023-07-18 17:16:44 +0800 (2023-07-18 09:16:44 +0000)
OS Version: iPhone OS 16.4.1 (20E252)
Report Version: 104

Exception Type: SIGSEGV
Exception Codes: SEGV_ACCERR at 0x31
Crashed Thread: 0

Thread 0 Crashed:
0 libobjc.A.dylib 0x000000019288016c 0x19287c000 + 16748 objc_release (in libobjc.A.dylib) + 8
1 ThirdControlFramework 0x0000000107af5b84 0x107a44000 + 727940 -[MASViewConstraint install] (in ThirdControlFramework) (MASViewConstraint.m:333)
2 ThirdControlFramework 0x0000000107a799e4 0x107a44000 + 219620 -[MASCompositeConstraint install] (in ThirdControlFramework) (MASCompositeConstraint.m:174)
3 ThirdControlFramework 0x0000000107aab4c4 0x107a44000 + 423108 -[MASConstraintMaker install] (in ThirdControlFramework) (MASConstraintMaker.m:46)
4 ThirdControlFramework 0x0000000107a5a5b0 0x107a44000 + 91568 -[UIView(MASAdditions) mas_makeConstraints:] (in ThirdControlFramework) (View+MASAdditions.m:18)
5 MyApp 0x0000000100be5100 0x1000c0000 + 11686144 -[CARSeriesSpecDiffImageCell setupSubViews] (in MyApp) (CARSeriesSpecDiffImageCell.m:50)
6 MyApp 0x0000000100be4f38 0x1000c0000 + 11685688 -[CARSeriesSpecDiffImageCell initWithFrame:] (in MyApp) (CARSeriesSpecDiffImageCell.m:40)
7 UIKitCore 0x000000019b8d9660 0x19b843000 + 616032 -[UICollectionView _dequeueReusableViewOfKind:withIdentifier:forIndexPath:viewCategory:] (in UIKitCore) + 992
8 UIKitCore 0x000000019b8d8950 0x19b843000 + 612688 -[UICollectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath:] (in UIKitCore) + 84
9 MyApp 0x0000000100673c44 0x1000c0000 + 5979204 -[CARSeriesSpecDiffContentView collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:] (in MyApp) (CARSeriesSpecDiffView.m:242)
10 UIKitCore 0x000000019b98cb50 0x19b843000 + 1350480 -[UICollectionView _createPreparedCellForItemAtIndexPath:withLayoutAttributes:applyAttributes:isFocused:notify:] (in UIKitCore) + 980
11 UIKitCore 0x000000019bf3c938 0x19b843000 + 7313720 -[UICollectionView _createVisibleViewsForSingleCategoryAttributes:limitCreation:fadeForBoundsChange:] (in UIKitCore) + 1120
12 UIKitCore 0x000000019bf3cc10 0x19b843000 + 7314448 -[UICollectionView _createVisibleViewsForAttributes:fadeForBoundsChange:notifyLayoutForVisibleCellsPass:] (in UIKitCore) + 288
13 UIKitCore 0x000000019b86c9e0 0x19b843000 + 170464 -[UICollectionView _updateVisibleCellsNow:] (in UIKitCore) + 1612
14 UIKitCore 0x000000019b86c2a4 0x19b843000 + 168612 -[UICollectionView layoutSubviews] (in UIKitCore) + 304
15 UIKitCore 0x000000019b847ef4 0x19b843000 + 20212 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] (in UIKitCore) + 1920
16 QuartzCore 0x000000019ad024ac 0x19acf8000 + 42156 CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) (in QuartzCore) + 500
17 UIKitCore 0x000000019b912468 0x19b843000 + 849000 -[UIView(Hierarchy) layoutBelowIfNeeded] (in UIKitCore) + 296
18 UIKitCore 0x000000019b873f58 0x19b843000 + 200536 +[UIView(Animation) performWithoutAnimation:] (in UIKitCore) + 76
19 UIKitCore 0x000000019b98be14 0x19b843000 + 1347092 -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:willDisplay:] (in UIKitCore) + 1720
20 UIKitCore 0x000000019b95fb2c 0x19b843000 + 1166124 -[UITableView _updateVisibleCellsForRanges:createIfNecessary:] (in UIKitCore) + 604
21 UIKitCore 0x000000019b89a2e0 0x19b843000 + 357088 -[UITableView _updateVisibleCellsNow:] (in UIKitCore) + 1100
22 UIKitCore 0x000000019b899dc8 0x19b843000 + 355784 -[UITableView layoutSubviews] (in UIKitCore) + 148
23 UIKitCore 0x000000019b847ef4 0x19b843000 + 20212 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] (in UIKitCore) + 1920
24 QuartzCore 0x000000019ad024ac 0x19acf8000 + 42156 CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) (in QuartzCore) + 500
25 QuartzCore 0x000000019ad15a28 0x19acf8000 + 121384 CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) (in QuartzCore) + 148
26 QuartzCore 0x000000019ad26e54 0x19acf8000 + 192084 CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*, double, double*) (in QuartzCore) + 444
27 QuartzCore 0x000000019ad563c0 0x19acf8000 + 385984 CA::Transaction::commit() (in QuartzCore) + 648
28 QuartzCore 0x000000019ad40374 0x19acf8000 + 295796 CA::Transaction::flush_as_runloop_observer(bool) (in QuartzCore) + 88
29 UIKitCore 0x000000019bd405f4 0x19b843000 + 5232116 _UIApplicationFlushCATransaction (in UIKitCore) + 52
30 UIKitCore 0x000000019be90e00 0x19b843000 + 6610432 _UIUpdateSequenceRun (in UIKitCore) + 84
31 UIKitCore 0x000000019c4f4944 0x19b843000 + 13310276 schedulerStepScheduledMainSection (in UIKitCore) + 144
32 UIKitCore 0x000000019c4f3ea0 0x19b843000 + 13307552 runloopSourceCallback (in UIKitCore) + 92
33 CoreFoundation 0x00000001998a8208 0x1997d5000 + 864776 CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION (in CoreFoundation) + 28
34 CoreFoundation 0x00000001998b4864 0x1997d5000 + 915556 __CFRunLoopDoSource0 (in CoreFoundation) + 176
35 CoreFoundation 0x00000001998396c8 0x1997d5000 + 411336 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 (in CoreFoundation) + 244
36 CoreFoundation 0x000000019984f1c4 0x1997d5000 + 500164 __CFRunLoopRun (in CoreFoundation) + 828
37 CoreFoundation 0x00000001998544dc 0x1997d5000 + 521436 CFRunLoopRunSpecific (in CoreFoundation) + 612
38 GraphicsServices 0x00000001d4ab435c 0x1d4ab3000 + 4956 GSEventRunModal (in GraphicsServices) + 164
39 UIKitCore 0x000000019bbe037c 0x19b843000 + 3789692 -[UIApplication _run] (in UIKitCore) + 888
40 UIKitCore 0x000000019bbdffe0 0x19b843000 + 3788768 UIApplicationMain (in UIKitCore) + 340
41 MyApp 0x00000001000c77fc 0x1000c0000 + 30716 main (in MyApp) (main.m:0)
42 ??? 0x00000001b8cdcdec 0x0 + 0
```

I have request a issue the official repository, here: https://github.com/SnapKit/Masonry/issues/607
but
nobody response.

my question is ,what kind of scene , the masonary may crash in file MASViewConstraint of line 333
and finally crashed in libobjc.A.dylib +8